# In a macOS Cocoa application, How to show only the first 'x' elements that match a NSPredicate in a NSOutlineView populated with a NSTreeController?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I am developing a macOS proof of concept project. I have, in the main window, a NSOutlineView populated with a NSTreeController via Cocoa bindings and Core Data. Under the NSOutlineView, I have a search field and a "Recents" button, a bit like Xcode has in the project navigator. My Core Data model object has a "modifiedAt" property and, when the user selects the "Recents" button, I would like to show only the last 10 modified files in the OutlineView. Any suggestions on how to achieve that ? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Just an idea: Find the 10 files and hide the other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `fetchLimit` on your `NSFetchRequest` to be the number you want (10 in your example).

Comment: @alfonso-tesauro if this worked for you, please accept it to remove your question from the Open Questions list on SO.  If it didn't, a follow up comment to clarify why or what's not working for you would allow us to follow up.

Comment: This did not totally work for me, because I think I am using a NSTreeController and bindings. I think your solution is valid when using an outline's view datasource and delegate.

Comment: If that's the reason then take a look at NSTreeController's superclass which allows you to access the NSFetchRequest that populates the model and the fetch request has the fetchLimit field you need to set.

Comment: I haven't used this in exactly this setup (bindings) but the documentation implies this should work here also.

Comment: Sorry I missed the NSTreeController aspect of your question.  Looks harder to use in that context.  Without a bit more code for context I'm not sure, but it looks like because you're using it in the recents button case you aren't showing the whole hierarchical list but just a flat list and so you could in fact modify the tree control query with the fetchLimit specified as I noted in my comment above (similar to what you do for the search presumably?).